# How to add one day to the date set in admin form in magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

This question is based on this previously asked question :

[Magento custom module date field saving date to one day before the selected date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998797/magento-custom-module-date-field-saving-date-to-one-day-before-the-selected-date/9014749#9014749) !!!

So now i want to add one day custom way instead, after finding no answer from previous question.

```
if ($data['start_date'] != NULL)
{
    $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($data['start_date'], Zend_Date::DATE_SHORT);
    $model->setStartDate($date->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
}
```

How will i add one day to it ?

Comment: You are aware that you have syntax error in your code, right?

Comment: @atif please post valid, error free code, or the only responses you you will get will be along the lines of "fix that syntax error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using explode function, setting time to 00 and saving data solved my problem

```
if($data['start_date'] != NULL )
{
$start_time_array = explode("/", $data['start_date']);
$start_time = $start_time_array[2]."-".$start_time_array[0]."-".$start_time_array[1]." 00:00:00";
$model->setStartDate($start_time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% familiar with magento, however using PHP's date functions your could try this:

```
$day = date('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', strtotime($data['start_date'].' +1 day'));
$model->setStartDate($day);
```

This doesn't include validation but it's a start.

Comment: i am aware of this function and i did tried to make it work with my code but i couldn't figure it out, that's why i posted it here

Comment: have you tried the about though? I'm fairly sure it'll work if your input format is sensible.